# How to find executables

Tags: find

I know there is a find switch. but I want to know how to search a specific type of file. For example I need kind of terminal command which search for only **executable files**.

Comment: Define **executable**?  Almost every file in Linux can be executable.

Comment: those files which in termial by type ./myfile they run

Comment: I know there is -fstype but I do not know to how?

Comment: File System type, `fstype` is used in Linux environment which states the file system type being used.

Comment: @Mitch ok ok I think I can use that I saw that on man find. My qesestion is how to find thoses file which by chmod +x myfile we make them executable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
find . -perm -u+x -type f
```

If you want to find everything that could possibly be executable, you could look at mime-types or `file` output.  That would be counter-productive though since you couldn't possibly catch every script.

References:
[The man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247563/how-can-i-find-files-that-only-has-the-certain-permission-for-owner-using-bash)

Answer (score 10):

This also works,

```
find ~ -type f -executable
```

List all executable files inside your `/home/$USER` directory.

From `man find`

```
-executable
          Matches files which are executable  and  directories  which  are
          searchable  (in  a file name resolution sense).  This takes into
          account access control lists  and  other  permissions  artefacts
          which  the  -perm  test  ignores.   This  test  makes use of the
          access(2) system call, and so can be fooled by NFS servers which
          do UID mapping (or root-squashing), since many systems implement
          access(2) in the client's kernel and so cannot make use  of  the
          UID  mapping  information held on the server.  Because this test
          is based only on the result of the access(2) system call,  there
          is  no  guarantee  that  a file for which this test succeeds can
          actually be executed.
```